# Is Gradle required for an Android app to run in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project that I can import to android studio. It opens but refuses to run. The file contains 4 folders (.idea, gen, java, res) and 2 files (AndroidManifest.xml and project.apk). I can't seem to run the app. When I import it, Android studio tells me "This project does not use the Gradle and migrate project to gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Gradle is required for apps developed in or migrated to Android studio.

> Android Studio’s build system is based on Gradle and uses build
>   configuration files written in Groovy syntax for ease of extensibility
>   and customization.

Since the whole build system is based on Gradle, you're stuck using it! Not a bad thing, Gradle is pretty great.

I have migrated quite a few projects to Android studio, for the most part it has been quick and painless.

There's a nice guide to help you migrate to Android Studio over at the Android development site: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

Comment: Do you migrate it using a new project or the manual procedure? Thanks.

Comment: I migrated using the `Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)` option from the start page of Android Studio. There's a fair amount of manual work to be done, but it mostly involves getting familiarized with Gradle